# Adding FlutterFragment to Activity?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to add flutter app as a fragment in Native android Activity.
For flutter i have used the default counter app
and on Native Android side i have used the Default navigation drawer Template

I'm trying to add the flutter app when user clicks on gallery tile in the Navigation Drawer

```
class GalleryFragment : FragmentActivity() {
companion object {
    // Define a tag String to represent the FlutterFragment within this
    // Activity's FragmentManager. This value can be whatever you'd like.
    private const val TAG_FLUTTER_FRAGMENT = "flutter_fragment"
}

    // Declare a local variable to reference the FlutterFragment so that you
    // can forward calls to it later.
    private var flutterFragment: FlutterFragment? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Inflate a layout that has a container for your FlutterFragment. For
        // this example, assume that a FrameLayout exists with an ID of
        // R.id.fragment_container.
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main)

        // Get a reference to the Activity's FragmentManager to add a new
        // FlutterFragment, or find an existing one.
        val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager

        // Attempt to find an existing FlutterFragment, in case this is not the
        // first time that onCreate() was run.
        flutterFragment = fragmentManager
            .findFragmentByTag(TAG_FLUTTER_FRAGMENT) as FlutterFragment?

        // Create and attach a FlutterFragment if one does not exist.
        if (flutterFragment == null) {
            var newFlutterFragment = FlutterFragment.withCachedEngine("my_engine").build<FlutterFragment>()
            flutterFragment = newFlutterFragment
            fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(
                    R.id.nav_host_fragment,
                    newFlutterFragment,
                    TAG_FLUTTER_FRAGMENT
                )
                .commit()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to add FlutterFragment with fragment manager.
Fragment and FlutterFragment Mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation, add Flutter to Fragment still is experimental. For more details read this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Experimental:-Add-Flutter-Fragment

Comment: they have added it to official docs. here's the [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-fragment?tab=launch-with-rendermode-kotlin-tab)